# Cannot webdriver.get(url) an IP address in Selenium 3

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

So I wrote a python script that uses Selenium 2 to do various things to my modem. This fully works.

I am now busy updating the script to use Selenium 3, but I immediately ran into a problem where I cannot even get to the login page of the modem. The problem seems to be with the `get()`.

First of all it now crashes when given a fake URL. I then gave it the Google URL and it works perfectly, but now I need to go to the modem's IP. But when I use `driver.get(_rout_ip)`, where `_rout_ip` is **10.0.0.2**, it just appends the IP address to the Google URL. Removing the `get` for the fake URL is not an option since for some reason it is required as it cannot directly go to the modem ip.

The code for getting the webdriver instance is below

```
def get_driver():
    """
    Get an instance of a webdriver that is initialized to the router login page
    :return: A webdriver instance
    """

    if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + '\\' + _driver_name):
        print('ERROR: The specified driver does not exist, %s' % (os.getcwd() + '\\' + _driver_name))
        exit()

    print "Initializing the webdriver"

    # Set the path to the driver to be used
    os.environ["webdriver.gecko.driver"] = os.getcwd() + '\\' + _driver_name

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    # Go to a fake website. This is needed since it cannot go to the modem directly for some reason
    try:
        driver.get('http://poop_smells_nice.com')
    except Exception:
        print('WOOT')

    waiter.sleep(_SLEEP_TIME)  # Pause a bit to be safe

    print "Switching to the router login page"

    # Go to the modem ip
    driver.get(_rout_ip)

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    return driver
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`10.0.0.2` is not a URL and so the browser falls back on searching for it. Try `http://10.0.0.2/`

Comment: OK that was an easy fix. Weird though, 10.0.0.2 worked just fine in Selenium 2. But oh well